# Error with @CompileStatic on grails service that uses google Cache

Tags: grails, groovy

Using grails 2.3.2, Java 1.6.0_65, trying to compile the following placed in the services directory. Even if it is not a service, and just put in the src/groovy directory, it still causes the same compile error.

I installed groovy 2.1.9 (and tried 2.2.0) which appears to be the version used by grails 2.3.2 and ran `groovyc -cp quava-13.0.1.jar TestCache.groovy` and it worked fine. So it appears to be something related to grails.

```
package somewhere

import com.google.common.cache.Cache
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class TestCacheService {
    private final Cache<URL, String> cache

    TestCacheService() {
        cache = null
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
General error during instruction selection: sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:462)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3127)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3086)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:113)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:66)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:202)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.declaredAnnotations(Method.java:693)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:686)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:175)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:362)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:258)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getInterfaces(ClassNode.java:353)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.declaresInterface(ClassNode.java:945)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.implementsInterface(ClassNode.java:925)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.getResultType(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:2629)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:421)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression.visit(BinaryExpression.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:69)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:193)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:1435)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1051)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitClass(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:162)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompilationVisitor.visitClass(StaticCompilationVisitor.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompileTransformation.visit(StaticCompileTransformation.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.visitClass(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$2.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:176)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1036)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:572)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:506)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:215)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.runCompiler(Groovyc.java:1104)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:1155)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Grailsc.compile(Grailsc.java:78)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:770)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
```

Is this a known bug?
Any workaround?

Comment: I add the groovy tag since it's a groovy compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Cache class uses the Nullable annotation. I had multiple nullable annotation implementations on my classpath. I think removing 'edu.washington.cs.types.checker:checker-framework:1.6.4' from the classpath solved this problem.